# How do I delay execution of a delegate method of one protocol until the delegate method of another protocol has completed execution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, block

In the .m file ClassroomCollectionViewController, I have the following instance variable declared:

```
@implementation ClassroomCollectionViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *students;
}
```

This array is populated in the following delegate method of the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate protocol, which ClassroomCollectionViewController implements.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if (connection == _getStudentsEnrolledInClassConnection)
    {
        // Parse the JSON that came in
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_receivedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

        if (jsonArray.count > 0)
        {
            students = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            // Populate the students array
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
            {
                Student *studentInClass = [Student new];

                studentInClass.name = jsonArray[i][@"name"];
                studentInClass.profile = jsonArray[i][@"profile"];
                studentInClass.profileImageName = jsonArray[i][@"profile_image_name"];

                [students addObject:studentInClass];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the following delegate method of another protocol, namely the UICollectionViewDelegate, the students array populated above is used to construct the individual cells of the collection view.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ClassmateCollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView
       dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ClassmateCell"
       forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image;
    long row = [indexPath row];

    image = [UIImage imageNamed:[students[row] profileImageName]];

    myCell.imageView.image = image;
    myCell.classmateNameLabel.text = [students[row] name];

    return myCell;
}
```

The problem is that the students array is not yet populated by the time that the second of the two delegate methods above executes, which results in there being no data for the cells in the collection view to display.

The obvious solution to this problem is to delay the execution of the second method until the first one has finished executing (thus ensuring that the students array will be populated by the time the cells in the collection view are constructed). But I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to make this so in this particular context - since I have no control over when the second delegate method is invoked. I have considered using blocks and multithreading in order to solve this, but have failed at coming up with a solution that is relevant for this specific problem.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks very much,
Jay

Comment: Try reloading collection view `[self.collectionView reloadData];` at the end of web service execution. ie. after populating `students ` array.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so much. It worked! Is there any way for me to rate your answer as the best?

Comment: i'll put this as answer so you can mark it as accepted answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, connect an `IBOutlet` to `collection view` and

in your `connectionDidFinishLoading:` method

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

   //All other codes for populating `students` array

   [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delay execution of the collection view, you need to wait until the connectionDidFinishLoading calls.

Its pretty simple you can reload collection view from connectionDidFinishLoading method.

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

This is design problem. It suppose to go like this (MVC patern):

1. some service is receiving data by `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` sends results to model.
2. model enforces main thread, updates its data and posts some notification
3. view controller is registered for model notification and properly reacts on those notifications. Like `[self.collectionView reloadData];` or `[self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths: indexPaths];` and so on.